# gh-pages doesn't show site

Tags: npm, github-pages

I'm trying to create site by gh-pages after I'm run `npm run deploy` and it created `gh-pages` branch and when I'm go through the link that give in the sitting this show.

[image: 404 error]

Could anyone tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Your image shows an URL https://sovannak22.github.com/mywebsite.

That looks like a [project pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)

> A Project Pages site for a personal account is available at `http(s)://<username>.github.io/<projectname>`.

Don't forget an URL is case-sensitive.

Considering your GitHub account URL is https://github.com/Sovannak22, you should:

- have a repo at https://github.com/Sovannak22/mywebsite ([which I don't see](https://github.com/Sovannak22?tab=repositories))
- use the URL https://Sovannak22.github.com/mywebsite.